# ExtJS. Hide all components within a container

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a window in which I am rendering a number of components like panels etc.

Is there a way I can hide all the components contained in window without having to hide them individually? Something like,

```
Ext.getComponent('myWindow').hideAllComponents();
```

I am using extjs 3.4.

Comment: why not make all components in a container and then hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, you do not want to hide your window, but the elements in your window. So can do this:

```
// get window, get element, get all direct children with css selector '*'
var children = Ext.get('myWindow').getEl().down('*')

// hide them all
Ext.each(children,function(child){child.hide();});
```

Comment: I want to hide all children contained in window when window is hidden. I used a method similar to what you have suggested to hide children of the window but I wanted to know if there is an easy, fast and better way of doing this. In this method you are still hiding the children manually and individually.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting style for your container

```
Ext.get('myWindow').setStyle('display','none');
```

Comment: I could not find setStyle function in the documentation of Extjs 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `myWindow` is a reference to your window, you can use:

```
Ext.each(myWindow.items.items, function(cmp) { cmp.hide(); });
```

The other answers mention [Ext.get](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-get) but that retrieves DOM elements, not components.

See also: [ExtJS hide all child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050546/extjs-hide-all-child-components)