# ExtJS hide all child components

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Consider:

```
Ext.Array.each(myContainer.query('> *'), function(cmp) { cmp.hide(); });
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: For the general case I think this is a good solution. What containers are you talking about ?

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question is bad. Your solution is fine.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - I thought so too, which is why I asked this one!

Comment: I have posted my approach as an answer on the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach uses a query which takes more resources. A more efficient way may be just:

```
Ext.each(myContainer.items.items, function(cmp) { cmp.hide(); });
```

Since you already have a reference to myContainer, there's no point of querying for its children as you already have access to them.

If you want it even more efficient, you can also write your own for loop and iterate across **myContainer.items.items**.